# How do I put this code outside the main function?

Tags: c

This is currently works fine but is inside my main function

```
while((strcmp(user_day, "Australia")) && (strcmp(user_day, "Japan")))
    {
        printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");
        scanf("%s", &country);
        case_change(country); // function to lowercase any uppercaseletter //
    }
```

How do I put this into a separate function. (basically another .c file) ?
I tried doing something like this but it keeps giving a segmentation fault.

```
int main()
{
scanf("%s", &country);
testing_function(country);
}

int testing_function(char * country) 
{
    while((strcmp(user_day, "Australia")) && (strcmp(user_day, "Japan")))
    {
        printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");
        scanf("%s", &country);
        case_change(country); 
    }
return(country);
}
```

PS: Im still not done with what happens with "country". So I want to keep it as a string, if that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive and http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 2):

No matter if `country` is an array or a pointer, doing

```
scanf("%s", &country);
```

is wrong.

If `country` is an array, that will give you a pointer to the array, and it will be of type `char (*)[SOME_SIZE]`. If `country` is a pointer (which it is in your function) then `&country` is a pointer *to the pointer* and will have type `char **`. Neither are correct types, as the `"%s"` format expects a pointer to a `char`, of type `char *`.

Simple solution, and probably what will solve your crash, is to not use the address-of operator. Simply do

```
scanf("%s", country);  // Note, no address-of operator
```

---

There are a couple of other possible causes for the crash though, but it's hard to say anything more specific about them since you don't show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

problem is while loop because it is infinite loop

use `if`  instead of while

```
int main()
{
scanf("%s", country);
testing_function(country);
}

int testing_function(char  country) 
{
    if((strcmp(user_day, "Australia")) && (strcmp(user_day, "Japan")))
    {
        printf("Please select only Australia or Japan");
        scanf("%s", &country);
        case_change(country); 
    }
return(country);
}
```

using same variable in functino & main will use same address

P.S if you want to use pointer pass address of variable then use pointer in function

Comment: what's wrong with the while loop, why is it infinite?

Comment: by the way what is the value of user_day its comparing with  maybe that is why its showing segmentation fault.

Comment: Your program will invoke undefined behaviour if the second `scanf` receives any input beyond its automatic nul terminator.

Comment: it's not in either case - if the string is neither "Australia" nor "Japan", the user will enter a new string. There's no infinite loop here.

Comment: @mangusta It *is* a possible infinite loop. The variable `user_day` is never modified inside the loop. Infinite loops won't lead to crashes though.

Comment: its not even initialised `user_day` so the error is segmentation fault

Comment: yeah, my bad, i missed user_day from my sight. if user_day is neither "Australia" nor "Japan", the user is going to end up entering "country" infinitely. That's not the reason for segmentation fault however. The reason has been pointed out in the second answer

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Since we don't know what `user_day` is *or* how it was initialized, that's impossible to say.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in that case country is also not defined

Comment: @nikhil sugandh "country" is passed as argument to the function, it doesn't need to be defined

Comment: @mangusta we are taking a scanf of the country  i think it should be defined first as `char country[20]` and then taken form console and then passed as an argument to the function.

Comment: @iLikePizza use or operator because if it is neither australia or Japan user must enter New country. And operator says when user county is autralia and Japan propmpt New country that's a bug